# Is the Hindu deity Ganesha considered vegetarian by Hindus?

Tags: nutrition, hinduism

In [Meat and Livestock Australia criticised for advert of vegetarian Hindu God Ganesha](http://mobile.abc.net.au/news/2017-09-05/lamb-ad-under-fire-for-portrayal-of-vegetarian-god-ganesha/8875048?pfmredir=sm), it's claimed that the Hindu deity Ganesha is regarded as vegetarian:

> Indian Society of Western Australia spokesman Nitin Vashisht said the ad was insensitive.
>
> "[He is a] vegetarian teetotaller, and that's really God for us and most of the Indian community.

However, [Meat is right, for these Ganesha worshippers](http://m.timesofindia.com/city/bengaluru/Meat-is-right-for-these-Ganesha-worshippers/articleshow/54275618.Cms) features some individuals making meat offerings to Ganesha, and does not explicitly say that this is unusual or that Ganesha is vegetarian.

Is Ganesha considered vegetarian by Hindus?

Comment: This question seems far better suited to [hinduism.se].

Comment: @jwodder although probably on-topic there, I try to ask questions about suspected false claims on Skeptics.SE if possible, to try to keep potentially nonsensical content here if possible.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Wait, where do you want nonsensical content?

Comment: I doubt this is answerable within the scope of the site. There is no such thing as *one* Hindu dogma, just like there isn't one for Islam, Christianity etc. Wouldn't the fact that this caused a controversy be proof that at least *some* Hindus consider him a vegetarian?

Comment: @Oddthinking by "nonsense", I mean things that no knowledgeable expert would say, like "jet fuel can't melt steel beams".

Comment: @Oddthinking and I think such content should be on Skeptics.SE, not other stack exchanges, where practical.

Comment: Ganesha is an elephant, no?  Therefore, he would logically (and I accept that logic plays small part in religion) be a vegetarian by his elephant nature, rather than out of principle.

Comment: @jamesqf, it's a little more complicated than that. Most traditions hold that he had a human head which was later replaced by an elephant's head. But from a strict biological sense, I'd concede that it would be hard for him to chew meat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific Australian ad involved lamb and there is a tradition of offering a lamb's head to Ganesha.

According to [Fact and Theory in Social Science](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fact_and_Theory_in_Social_Science/RRIGoyGFa-EC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%E2%80%9C%20%20sacrifices%20the%20lamb%20by%20decapitating%20it%20with%20a%20knife%20and%20offers%20the%20head%20to%20Ganesh%22%22&pg=PA213&printsec=frontcover) (1964) at pages 213-214:

> Still later in the winter comes Magh Cauth.  ... A figure of a lamb , made of sugar , is brought to the sanctified place . When the moon is rising , the younger brother of the father of the boy , or a Brahman , **sacrifices the lamb by decapitating it with a knife and offers the head to Ganesh**.

This same text is repeated in [Anthropology in the Development Process](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Anthropology_in_the_Development_Process/6ZqwAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) (1977).

Similarly, [Culture and Mental Health
Cross-cultural Studies · Volume 10](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Culture_and_Mental_Health/PrlrAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=ganesh%20lamb%20sacrifice&dq=ganesh%20lamb%20sacrifice&printsec=frontcover) (1959) at page 285 says:

> Magh Cauth or “ Magh fourth , ” as the name suggests , is observed on the fourth day of the dark half of the month of Magh. ... When the moon is rising , the lamb is " sacrificed ” by decapitation with a knife . Some families ask a Brahman to do this , but the more usual thing is to have the father ' s younger brother act in this capacity . The head is lifted up and offered to Ganesh...

According to [Nepal, Land of Gods, Goddesses, and Demons](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Nepal_Land_of_Gods_Goddesses_and_Demons/YDZuAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) (1985):

> Unlike in India , where Ganesh is a scrupulously vegetarian god , in Nepal , he is considered blood - thirsty , living near burning ghats and the abodes of evil spirits . So animal sacrifices are made to him regularly .

The book [A South Indian Subcaste: Social Organization and Religion of the Pramalai Kallar](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_South_Indian_Subcaste/eQduAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22an%20error%20from%20which%20the%20junior%20priest%20%27%20s%20family%20suffers%20%22&dq=%22an%20error%20from%20which%20the%20junior%20priest%20%27%20s%20family%20suffers%20%22&printsec=frontcover#spf=1613235127680) ([alternative link](https://archive.org/details/southindiansubca0000dumo/page/396/mode/2up)) lists Ganesh in the table on page 396 under both "vegetarian" gods and "meat eater" gods, vegetarian based upon what should be offered to Ganesh in principle, but meat-eater based upon what is offered to Ganesh in fact.

Overall, there is no consensus on whether or not Ganesh is vegetarian.